# How to add multiple initialised strings into and append() method

Tags: python, string, list, object, initialization

So I'm working on a simple code that works like a bag, this code currently can read and add singular initialised strings into an array that has been also initialised under all classes. Here's the code:

```
class Items:
# This class initializes the items name
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Bag:
    # This class adds the initialised items and reads anything in the bag
    def __init__(self, items, max_items):
        # max_items is the maximum capacity of the Bag
        self.items = items
        self.max_items = max_items
    
    def add_items(self):
        if len(self.items) < self.max_items:
            self.items.append(i.name) # <- Here is the problem at '(i.name)'
        
    def read_items(self):
        for item in self.items:
            print(item)  
            
            
i = Items("Item1")
i2 = Items("Item2")
b = Bag([], 10) # I'm just going to put example 10 strings for the max_items
b.add_items()
b.read_items()
```

The output of this code is "Item1".

I wanted the 'append()' method in 'add_items()' function to also add 'i2' initialisation and other initialisation that will be added in the future with any name that the user will put in automatically.

Comment: You want to add all the objects of the class ```Items``` using ```add_items()```. Is it?

Comment: yes, that's what i wanted

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is a list of items passed to your `add_items` function:

```py
def add_items(self, items: list):
    if (len(self.items) + len(items)) < self.max_items:
        for i in items:
            self.items.append(i.name)
```

You then later call it with

```
b.add_items([i, i2])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add multiple items at the same time without iterations, you can use `extend()` rather than `append()`, but you have to redefine `add_items()` accordingly:

```
def add_items(self, *args): # args will collect any number of items you pass in a tuple
        if len(self.items) + len(args) <= self.max_items:
            self.items.extend([i.name for i in args])

i = Items("Item1")
i2 = Items("Item2")
b = Bag([], 10)
b.add_items(i, i2)
b.read_items()
# output:
Item1
Item2
```

This would be a Pythonic way to do the job without unexpected behaviors.